# Filter a map to have only the given set of keys

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a `Map<K, V>` named `myMap`, and a `List<K>` named `myList`. I want to create a submap containing only those entries whose keys are in `myList`. I can see the following ways:

```kotlin
    val newMap1 = myList.associateWith { myMap[it] }
    val newMap2 = myMap.filterKeys { it in myList }
    val newMap3 = myMap - (myMap.keys - myList)
    val newMap4 = myMap.toMutableMap().apply { keys.retainAll(myList) }
```

Unfortunately, none of these seem to convey directly what I want to do. I was looking for something like `val newMap = myMap.retainAll(list)`, but couldn't find it. Is there some method similar to this?

Comment: Why do you think `myMap.filterKeys { it in myList }` doesn't convey what you want to do? It's almost the english sentence you used to describe it. I would definitely go with that one from a readability standpoint (possibly using a set instead of a list if it can get big)

Comment: `retainAll()` sounds to me like a mutating operation. Also, it doesn't mention "keys", so I wouldn't be sure how does it retain items, I personally prefer `filterKeys()`. Please be aware you can use `myMap.filterKeys(myList::contains)` if it makes more sense to you. Or you can create an extension which filters keys by providing a collection of keys.

Comment: Do you want the result of your operation be like a "view" on the original map, like [subList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/sub-list.html) for lists?

Comment: Not sure why none of these "convey directly what you want to do", but how about just writing your own extension function called `retainAll`?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I think Joffrey and broot have convinced me that `filterKeys` is what I actually want after all. So I'm voting to close my own question.

Comment: @greyhairredbear that's an interesting question. I was looking for something with the same behaviour as `filterKeys`, but something returning a view might also be useful. However, there's no precedent, for example, there's no view of "sublist of list1 containing only elements in list2". If we were to have such a view, it should be more general than just for maps.